# How to save an Image or File Stream in application's settings? UWP C#

Tags: c#, image, uwp, settings, filestream

I have a List View with some ListViewItems and each one contains a TextBox and an Image.

The user can add or remove these ListViewItems, so I would like to save them in the settings each time the app is closed and load each time it is opened.

I managed to save the TextBoxes' texts in the settings and load them, **but how to save and load Images / Image Sources / File Streams?**

The images are created when the user chooses an image in a FileOpenPicker and then a Bitmap Image is created with a File Stream to that chosen Image, as the ListViewItem's image source.

```
private async void openFileInputEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage tmpimg = new BitmapImage();
                await tmpimg.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                imglist.Add(tmpimg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("File not chosen", "No chosen Image");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
            imglist.Add(new BitmapImage());
        }
    }
```

The bitmap images for all the ListViewItems' images are stored in a list of bitmap images (`List<BitmapImage>`) and they are chosen by choosing the last item on the list (`imglist[imglist.Count-1]`)

**I would like to save and load this Images / their source / file stream to their source, is there any way to do that?**

I could save paths to the images, but I can't later create an Image with the path as its source, it has to be a file stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to save an Image or File Stream in application's settings? UWP C#

`LocalSettings` does not support store the big data, I'm afraid you can't store the BitmapImage into `LocalSettings` directly, for your scenario, we suggest you store your image in the app's [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder?view=winrt-19041) and access them with [uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#scheme-name-ms-appdata).

Comment: And how to do that if the images' sources are from the local computer (they are chosen with the FileOpenPicker)?

Comment: please check uwp  [uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#scheme-name-ms-appdata), you could access file with uri.

Comment: But how to get the uri of the chosen file from the computer?

Comment: You just need to get the image file name and the stored folder, for example, if you store the image file into `localstate`, you could get the uri like `<Image Source="ms-appdata:///local/img.png" />`.   `ms-appdata:///local` =  `localstate foder`  img.png is your image name

Comment: But what about the situation when the file is stored on the C drive (C:/image.png). Can you make an uri out of that? Or can you somehow copy the chosen files to the app's folder to make them always accessible?

Comment: We don't suggest  load the file from c d disk directly,  and if you do want to load the file with above path you could enable uwp `broadFileSystemAccess` capability and use `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` to access, for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) .

Comment: Ok, I think [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39111925) here is what I was looking for as a solution. Thanks for help anyways.